# Nagios service restart is failing on CentOS

Tags: centos, centos-6, nagios

Nagios restart service is failing with the error:

> /etc/init.d/nagios: line 153: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

It's only happening on CentOS (6x); 
For Ubuntu & Redhat this issue does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. Just to get it running, I commented out the printstatus_nagios function from /etc/init.d/nagios (lines 255 and the entire section on line 142). At least nagios started back up for me, just can't get a status on the process is all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this might relate to Nagios Core 4.4.3, and it appears to be an update made on or since 19th January 2019.  Presumably it will be patched in due course, however to remedy a missing "fi" is required, I suspect between lines 145 and 146 (i.e. a new line 146).

Having updated as referenced I'm now able to restart the Nagios service again.

Answer (score 0):

In the nagios rpm installed Feb02, the file /etc/init.d/nagios is missing a `fi` for the `if status_nagios` in the block of printstatus_nagios.